# Shapes is not a class or namespace

Tags: c++, linux, enums, g++

I just switched from windows (Visual Studio) to Linux (Mint) and now I'm using QTCreator for plain c++ projects. Though everything seems to be working fine when I try to compile the project I was working on with VS2010, g++ won't accept the following syntax.

```
enum{
    LINE,
    POLYGON,
    TRIANGLE
}Shapes;
```

... much code ...

```
gEngine.AddItem(1,0,Shapes::POLYGON,0,0,0);
gEngine.AddItem(1,2,Shapes::POLYGON,400,400,-1);
gEngine.AddItem(1,2,Shapes::POLYGON,800,400,-1);
gEngine.AddItem(1,2,Shapes::POLYGON,800,800,-1);
gEngine.AddItem(1,2,Shapes::POLYGON,400,800,-1);
gEngine.AddItem(1,2,Shapes::POLYGON,400,400,-1);
gEngine.AddItem(1,1,Shapes::POLYGON,0,0,0);
```

(G++) Returning: Shapes is not a class or a namespace ; even though it compiles perfectly with VS2010.

Comment: Use `enum class`, or just `POLYGON`. `enum` doesn't create its own scope.

Comment: Exactly what @chris said. VC++ has a stupid extension that allows that syntax but it's not valid C++.

Comment: @SethCarnegie yup but it does give you a warning even thought it incorrectly accepts this as valid syntax.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Well that's clever.  I actually use the `Shapes::Line` for clarity even though it isn't portable, I'll use your trick in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no type `Shapes` but you have declared a variable called `Shapes`.

To define the type use `enum Shapes {...}` then create variables of that type.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want

```
enum Shapes{
  LINE,
  POLYGON,
  TRIANGLE
};
```

This declares an enum type Shapes, but what you had defines a variable Shapes of the type (with no name) which was an enum.

Comment: This is the syntax of C back before C++.  Somehow Visual Studio was being forgiving.

Comment: The code in the OP creates an object named `Shapes` of the type of a nameless `enum`.  Then VC++ is allowing him to access the enumerated values through the _instance_ of the enum variable.  I think.

Comment: ~Mooing Duck, I agree that's what's happening.